# comparing 2 array list and loop through contents

Tags: java, arraylist

I am retrieving elements from 2 array lists and looping and comparing them.
Is there a better way to loop though this?. It little slow and doesn't seem efficient

```
       String Name = employee.get(0).getEmpName();
       for(int i = 0; i < employee.size(); i++)
       {
           if (Name.equals(employee.get(i).getEmpName()))
           {
               for (int j = 0; j < employer.size(); j++)
               {
                   if (Name.equals(employer.get(i).getEmpChoice()) &&           (employers.get(j).getCompChoice() == 1))
                   {
                       if (!Test.contains(Name) ||  
                           !Test.contains(employers.get(j).getCompName()))
                       {
                            Test += Name + employers.get(j).getCompName() + "\n";
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
           else
           {
               Name = employees.get(i).getEmpName();
               i--;
           }
       }
```

Comment: employer is the arraylist, what is employer**s**? and is `employer.getCompChoice()` unique?

Comment: What's the goal of your code?  I can't follow it.  Also, I see several problems, such as using `i` to index into the `employer` list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use foreach statements, they are easier on the eyes

```
for(Employee emp : employee)
```

Also a faster way would be to use a map to store the data. so you just have to iterate through one list.

```
Map<String,Employee> employees;
for(Employer emp : employer){
    if(employees.get(emp.getEmpChoice()).getCompChoice() == 1){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Depending on what implementation of `Map` you are using this may speed up your process. Also your code is more concise.

Comment: did you really understand the question and requirement before you posted the answer? I don't....